# ComponentObjectModelException when using Moyosoft Outlook Connector

Tags: java, outlook, connector

We are using [Moyosoft's Java Outlook Connector](http://www.moyosoft.com/joc/) and it works very well for us most of the time.

On a single machine (Windows 7 with Outlook 2010 installed) we get the following error :

```
com.moyosoft.connector.com.ComponentObjectModelException: Unable to create an
instance for the specified program ID (80080005)
    at com.moyosoft.connector.com.c.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.moyosoft.connector.com.c.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.moyosoft.connector.com.c.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.moyosoft.connector.com.c.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.moyosoft.connector.com.DispatchProxy.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.moyosoft.connector.com.c.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.moyosoft.connector.com.ComUtil.createDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.moyosoft.connector.ms.outlook.Outlook.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.moyosoft.connector.ms.outlook.Outlook.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

From the code :

```
Outlook outlook = new Outlook( );
```

On a different Windows7 machine with Outlook 2010, it works perfectly as expected.  Any suggestions as to what we are doing wrong or where we should look?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Outlook outlook = new Outlook(profile, password);
```

I had to provide a profile and a password to start
the values are for default so the textarea stay empty while profile is "Default".